# Float type displayed wrongly as float(4) instead of float

Tags: mysql

I am beginner to MySQL , need answer to below question.

```
CREATE TABLE FloatingPoint_Approxvalue1 (
    floatdata float(4),
    floatdata1 float(4,3),
    doubledata double(4,3)
);

describe FloatingPoint_Approxvalue1;
```

The result:

```
Field       Type        Null

floatdata   float       YES     
floatdata1  float(4,3)  YES     
doubledata  double(4,3) YES
```

As per my understanding , 'floatdata' field type should be displayed as float(4) instead of float.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Comment: What do you think `FLOAT(4)` does/means?